# UDP Client-Server application and Firewalls/NATs

Tags: networking, udp, firewall, windows-firewall

I have a simple client application which sends udp datagram to the server with known ip address and port and waits for respond. Client can be started on any computer or mobile device and it can be located behind several routers and firewalls... Server application listens  certain port for client's datagram and replies to the client's endpoint with an answer. Server application works on windows computer with properly configured firewall, etc. So, as I understand, this simple scheme should work regardless to client's location and his firewall settings. But it looks like it doesn't work in about 75% of configurations. Server receives request from the client in 100% of cases, but in 75% of cases client can't receive response from the server, i.e. it looks like it's always blocked by something (server attempts 10 times to send an answer to the client, but without luck, i.e. client doesn't receive anything). I tried many different configurations of client computers to figure out the reasons of these issues and what I've found:

1. In some cases simple windows firewall can block respond packets (But how it could be possible? As I understand, all respond packets must be forwarded back to the client regardless to firewall settings.)
2. Some Hardware firewalls or NATs also can block respond UDP packets. And again, I can't understand why it could be possible?

The question is - is there any reliable method to deliver an answer to client? As I know, many programs, such as Skype works fine with UDP even with all these network "obstacles".

Thank you!

Comment: Did you make sure the response comes from the proper source port on the server? Some forms of NAT are more strict about matching everything about the packet.

Comment: you are right, it was a reason ;(